# Keep tensorflow session inside docker?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow

I try to build docker with flask(API) and tensorflow(ML model).
Process of loading model to tf session was very long, so I decided to start it at the beginning and keep it in a RAM. Then my problem has start. My application stopped working for a docker. It works when I run it without(outside) docker.

Script for keeping tf session.

```
class TensorHelperAlign():
    def __init__(self):
        graph = tf.Graph()
        with graph.as_default():
            gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=1.0)
            sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options, log_device_placement=False))
            sess.as_default().__enter__()
            pnet, rnet, onet = create_mtcnn(sess, None)

        self.pnet = pnet
        self.rnet = rnet
        self.onet = onet

align_mtcnn_helper = TensorHelperAlign()
```

I based on facenet repo `https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/align/detect_face.py`

When I run `main` function in https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/blob/master/src/align/align_dataset_mtcnn.py this code in docker, my application stop at the step with pnet.
My diffrance is in line 51:

```
#    with graph.as_default():
#        gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=1.0)
#        sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options, #log_device_placement=False))
#        sess.as_default().__enter__()
#        pnet, rnet, onet = create_mtcnn(sess, None)
     pnet, rnet, onet = align_mtcnn_helper.pnet, align_mtcnn_helper.rnet, align_mtcnn_helper.onet
```

Instead of running it all the time, I keep it in a RAM.
Do you know a reason why this work outside of container and didn't work in it?
If I rollback this change my container works fine.

Comment: Could you include the relevant logs, i.e the python traceback of the crash?